# Spring Data, Mongo, and @TypeAlias: reading not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

**The issue**

Awhile back I started using MongoDB and Spring Data. I'd left most of the default functionality in place, and so all of my documents were stored in MongoDB with a `_class` field pointing to the entity's fully-qualified class name.

Right away that didn't "smell" right to me, but I left it alone. Until recently, when I refactored a bunch of code, and suddenly none of my documents could be read back from MongoDB and converted into their (refactored/renamed) Java entities. I quickly realized that it was because there was now a fully-qualified-classname mismatch. I also quickly realized that--given that I might refactor again sometime in the future--if I didn't want all of my data to become unusable I'd need to figure something else out.

**What I've tried**

So that's what I'm doing, but I've hit a wall. I *think* that I need to do the following:

- Annotate each entity with `@TypeAlias("ta")` where "ta" is a unique, stable string.
- Configure and use a different `TypeInformationMapper` for Spring Data to use when converting my documents back into their Java entities; it needs to know, for example, that a type-alias of "widget.foo" refers to `com.myapp.document.FooWidget`.

I determined that I should use a `TypeInformationMapper` of type `org.springframework.data.convert.MappingContextTypeInformationMapper`. Supposedly a MappingContextTypeInformationMapper will scan my entities/documents to find @TypeAlias'ed documents and store an alias->to->class mapping. But I can't pass that to my MappingMongoConverter; I have to pass a subtype of MongoTypeMapper. So I am configuring a `DefaultMongoTypeMapper`, and passing a List of one `MappingContextTypeInformationMapper` as its "mappers" constructor arg.

**Code**

Here's the relevant part of my spring XML config:

```
<bean id="mongoTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey" value="_class"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="mappers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mappingContextTypeMapper" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<bean id="mappingContextTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.convert.MappingContextTypeInformationMapper">
    <constructor-arg ref="mappingContext" />
</bean>

<bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="mappingContext" />
    <property name="mapKeyDotReplacement" value="__dot__" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="mongoTypeMapper"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
 </bean>
```

Here's a sample entity/document:

```
@Document(collection="widget")
@TypeAlias("widget.foo")
public class FooWidget extends Widget {

    // ...

}
```

One important note is that any such "Widget" entity is stored as a nested document in Mongo. So in reality you won't really find a populated "Widget" collection in my MongoDB instance. Instead, a higher-level "Page" class can contain multiple "widgets" like so:

```
@Document(collection="page")
@TypeAlias("page")
public class Page extends BaseDocument {

    // ...

    private List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();

}
```

**The error I'm stuck on**

What happens is that I can save a Page along with a number of nested Widgets in Mongo. But when I try to read said Page back out, I get something like the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.myapp.document.Widget]: Is it an abstract class?
```

I can indeed see pages in Mongo containing `"_class" : "page"`, with nested widgets also containing `"_class" : "widget.foo"`  It just appears like the mapping is not being applied in the reverse.

Is there anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent a bunch of time with my debugger and the Spring Data source code, and I learned that Spring Data isn't as good as it probably should be with polymorphism as it should be, especially given the schema-less nature of NoSQL solutions like MongoDB. But ultimately what I did was to write my own type mapper, and that wasn't too tough.

The main problem was that, when reading in my Page document, the default mappers used by Spring Data would see a collection called *widgets*, then consult the Page class to determine that widgets pointed to a List, then consult the Widget class to look for @TypeAlias information. What I needed instead was a mapper that scanned my persistent entities up front and stored an alias-to-class mapping for later use. That's what my custom type mapper does.

I wrote a [blog post discussing the details](http://foreignloops.blogspot.com/2014/11/spring-data-mongo-and-lazy-mappers.html).

Answer (score 9):

In the default setting, the `MappingMongoConverter` creates a `DefaultMongoTypeMapper` which in turn creates a `MappingContextTypeInformationMapper`.

That last class is the one responsible for maintaining the `typeMap` cache between `TypeInformation` and aliases.

That cache is populated in two places:

1. In the constructor, for each `mappingContext.getPersistentEntities()`
2. When writing an object of an aliased type.

So if you want to make sure the alias is recognized in any context, you need to make sure that all your aliased entities are part of `mappingContext.getPersistentEntities()`.

How you do that depends on your configuration. For instance:

- if you're using `AbstractMongoConfiguration`, you can overwrite its `getMappingBasePackage()` to return the name of a package containing all of your entities.
- if you're using spring boot, you can use `@EntityScan` to declare which packages to scan for entities
- in any case, you can always configure it with a custom set (from a static list or a custom scan) using `mongoMappingContext.setInitialEntitySet()`

One side note, for an entity to be discovered by a scan, it has to be annotated with either `@Document` or `@Persitent`.

More informations can be found in the [spring-data-commons Developer Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/developer-guide)

Comment: To those like me who tried this in 2019: MappingContextTypeInformationMapper is somewhat a red herring. Even latest spring-data-commons'es  MappingContextTypeInformationMapper  doesn't populate the `typeMap` in the constructor. The latter calls the `verify()` method only, but to be added to the cache the `createAliasFor()` should be called. So even if you add your types to the mappingContext.getPersistentEntities() it will not change anything.

Comment: I've annotated some types in a spcific package with both @Persistent and @TypeAlias, as well as added @EntityScan to my configuration pointed at that package. And yet, those types are not included in the MappingContext `initialEntitySet`. This whole mess has left a bad taste in my mouth around Spring Data Mongo.

Answer (score 4):

If you extend *AbstractMongoConfiguration*, you can override method *getMappingBasePackage* to specify the base package for your documents.

```
@Configuration
class RepositoryConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.example";
    }
```

}

**Update:** In spring-data-mongodb 2+ you should use:

```
    @Configuration
    class RepositoryConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
            @Override
            protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages(){
                return Arrays.asList("com.example");
            }
        }
```

because `getMappingBasePackage()` is no deprecated and won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use spring boot with auto-configuration, declaring the following bean can help:

```
@Bean
MongoManagedTypes mongoManagedTypes(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
throws ClassNotFoundException {
    
  return MongoManagedTypes.fromIterable(
    new EntityScanner(applicationContext).scan(Persistent.class));
}
```

Instead of scanning for `Document`s it will scan for both `Document` and `TypeAlias`, since both of these annotations are `Persistent`

Comment: Note this is only an option in Spring Data MongoDB 4.x and above.

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into the exact same issue. After more research I found out that my subclass was missing a repository. It appears that Spring Data is using the repositories to determine which concrete subclass to create and when it is missing, it falls back to the superclass which in this case is abstract.

So please try to add a FooWidgetRepository and map it to FooWidget with correct ID type. It might work in your case as well.

Answer (score -1):

*[Andreas Svensson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194122/2119598)* is right, this can be done much simpler than described by *[Dave Taubler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953556/2119598)*.

I posted a slightly more elaborate answer than Andreas' (including sample code) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387936/2119598). Excerpt:

> So all you need to do is to declare an "unused" Repository-Interface
>   for your sub-classes, just like you proposed as "unsafe" in your OP:

```
public interface NodeRepository extends MongoRepository<Node, String> { 
  // all of your repo methods go here
  Node findById(String id);
  Node findFirst100ByNodeType(String nodeType);
  ... etc.
}
public interface LeafType1Repository extends MongoRepository<LeafType1, String> {
  // leave empty
}
public interface LeafType2Repository extends MongoRepository<LeafType2, String> { 
  // leave empty
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I would have liked to comment on Andreas' post, but unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to comment on other author's posts

Comment: This means for X subclasses you must add X repositories - no good.