# how to retrieve objects when using inheritance in spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Say I have a class structure as follows, it is pretty basic inheritance:

```
Manager extends Person {
  private String name;

 Manager() {

 }
}

Clerk extends Person {
  private String salary;
}
```

In spring Data if I store these in Mongo, is it possible to configure it to map the correct class when I do a  getById. I assume i will have to store some class info?

What i dont want to do is the need to create seperate repository classes if i can avoid it, also i dont know what the object will be when i do a getById

Comment: Beware of the typo: `person` should be `Person`. I can't edit it (edits require 6+ characters), but make sure your error doesn't originate from this dumb typo ;)

Comment: Nope the error is not from the typo, so now back to the question?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have separate repositories? I'd have 3 PersonRepo, ManagerRepo, ClerkRepo.

Comment: Because im storing them internally in the same collection, i was hoping spring data might have some magic or some plugin i could use that would propulate the correct pojo. Could i not have a marker on the data.. perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring-data-mongodb MongoRepository to write data in your database according to your entity model, a `_class` field will be added to document roots and to complex property types (see this section). This fields store the fully qualified name of the Java class and it allows disambiguation when mapping from MongoDb Document to Spring data model.

However, if you only use [MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html) to read from your database, you need to tell Spring-data how to map your entities explicitly. You will need to [Override Mapping with Explicit Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters).

**`PersonReadConverter.class`**

```
public class PersonReadConverter implements Converter<Document, Person> {
@Override
    public Contact convert(Document source) {
        if (source.get("attribute_specific_to_Clerk") != null) {
            Clerk clerk = new Clerk();
            //Set attributes using setters or defined constructor
            return clerk;
        }
        else {
            Manager manager = new Manager()
            //Set attribute using setters or defined constructor
            return manager;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you have to [Register Spring Converters with the MongoConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters.xml).

You can find an example of my own at: [Spring Data Mongo - How to map inherited POJO entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194223/spring-data-mongo-how-to-map-inherited-pojo-entities)